# Evaluate field as expression in Logstash filter

Tags: logstash

I have one custom field in Logstash event defined as expression:

```
{ "customIndex" => "my-service-%{+YYYY.MM}" }
```

And filter that calculates index name for elasticsearch output plugin:

```
filter {
  if [customIndex] {
    mutate {
      add_field => { "indexName" => "custom-%{customIndex}" }
    } 
  } else {
    mutate {
      add_field => { "indexName" => "common-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" }
    }
  }
}
```

But for custom index it creates **invalid** name `custom-my-service-%{+YYYY.MM}` and does not evaluate `%{+YYYY.MM}` expression.

Is it possible to evaluate field and get `custom-my-service-2016.11`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can reformat your created field to this:

```
{ "customIndex" => "my-service-%Y.%m" }
```

Then this Ruby filter will do the trick:

```
ruby {
    init => "require 'date'"
    code => "event['indexName'] = 'custom-' + Date.today.strftime(event['customIndex'])"
}
```

[Here](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) is a documentation on placeholders you can use.

Comment: I don't have any problem with else part. I'm interested in if part. Even though, you suggestion doesn't work for me, because it requires hardcode time pattern in Logstash level and makes it not flexible.
My point is to make Logstash more flexible and receive date pattern as income part. So one application will use index per hour, another per day etc.

Comment: @moleksyuk Updated the answer